# DateTime + 12 hours showing same DateTime. Why?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, dateinterval

When I am increasing DateTime value by any hours, the result is OKAY, but when I increase it by 12 hours, it is not increasing.

---

Please see the following code for details:

```
$creation_date = new DateTime('2016-09-07 06:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$expiration_date = new DateTime('2016-09-07 06:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
```

When I increase the `$expiration_date` variable by 1 hour, 3 hour, 8 hour, 24 hours etc., the result is perfect. For example,

Case 1:

```
$expiration_date->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
echo "Creation Date: ".$creation_date->format('Asia/Kolkata')."<br/>Expiration Date: ".$expiration_date->format('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Result 1:
Creation Date: 2016-09-07 06:00:00
Expiration Date: 2016-09-07 07:00:00

Case 2:

```
$expiration_date->add(new DateInterval('PT3H'));
echo "Creation Date: ".$creation_date->format('Asia/Kolkata')."<br/>Expiration Date: ".$expiration_date->format('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Result 2:
Creation Date: 2016-09-07 06:00:00
Expiration Date: 2016-09-07 09:00:00

Case 3:

```
$expiration_date->add(new DateInterval('PT8H'));
echo "Creation Date: ".$creation_date->format('Asia/Kolkata')."<br/>Expiration Date: ".$expiration_date->format('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Result 3:
Creation Date: 2016-09-07 06:00:00
Expiration Date: 2016-09-07 02:00:00

Case 4:

```
$expiration_date->add(new DateInterval('PT24H'));
echo "Creation Date: ".$creation_date->format('Asia/Kolkata')."<br/>Expiration Date: ".$expiration_date->format('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Result 4:
Creation Date: 2016-09-07 06:00:00
Expiration Date: 2016-09-08 06:00:00

**But when I increase the `$expiration_date` variable by *12 hours*, the date is not getting increased!

They are showing the same datetime!**

Case 5:

```
$expiration_date->add(new DateInterval('PT12H'));
echo "Creation Date: ".$creation_date->format('Asia/Kolkata')."<br/>Expiration Date: ".$expiration_date->format('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Result 5:
Creation Date: 2016-09-07 06:00:00
Expiration Date: 2016-09-07 06:00:00

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess it's populating correctly, however your time format needs to be set to 24 hour, could you please check that?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/2g7r5 Works for me. Also `format('Asia/Kolkata')` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your code is correct, you need to just make sure it should show date time in 24hrs. 6pm + 12hrs = 6am

Answer (score 4, accepted):

8 hours gives you

```
Creation Date: 2016-09-07 06:00:00
Expiration Date: 2016-09-07 02:00:00
```

Do you really think that that 6 + 8 is 2 ? No, it is 14 which is 2pm
The same with 6 + 12 is 18 which is 6pm. Change format of displayed data to 24 hours ;)

Comment: Yes yes... its working! Thank you so much :) I was banging my head on my laptop after trying to figure out the issue for an hour! :D I changed it to 24 hours format. Now it is working fine. Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: Hehe, you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's populating correctly, however your time format needs to be set to 24 hour, could you please check that?

Answer (score 1):

The date format is the issue,

```
$expiration_date= new DateTime('2016-09-07 06:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$expiration_date->add(new DateInterval('PT8H'));
echo date_format($expiration_date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2016-09-07 14:00:00
```